# removeChild with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, addeventlistener, removechild

I'm just learning javascript. Testing stuff on the google Chrome Console I ended up with this:

```
<html>

<head></head>
<body>

<div id="divi">

<button id="butti">Click Me</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And Js:**

```
function cBoton (){
 var getDiv = document.getElementById("divi");
  getDiv.removeChild(getDiv.lastChild);
};

var getButton = document.getElementById("butti");
getButton.addEventListener("click", cBoton);
```

I expect the button to be deleted after one click. ¿Why works only after the second click?

tx!

Comment: Try putting `console.log(getDiv.lastChild)` in `cBoton` before you call `removeChild`.

Comment: instead of `lastChild`, it would be better if you use `lastElementChild` and if you want to remove button when clicking on it, maybe it would be better if you use `function cBoton(e) { e.target.parentElement.removeChild(e.target); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.lastChild` of the element in your markup is `""` (try `console.log(getDiv.lastChild)` to clarify).

Use this to be sure that you are deleting the desired element:

```
function cBoton() {
    var getDiv = document.getElementById("divi");
    getDiv.removeChild(getButton);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first click, the last child of `divi` is the text node containing the whitespace after the button, and this gets removed. On the second click, the button is the last child.

Answer (score -1):

Invaluable..

Modified the source;

```
/* .css */

div :nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

/*.js */

function addDiv() {
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode('textHere'); // add cell code here 
para.appendChild(node);
var element;
element = document.getElementById("div1"); // to add div id recursion
element.appendChild(para);
}

function cBoton (){
var getDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
getDiv.removeChild(getDiv.lastChild);
}

var getButton = document.getElementById("div1");
getButton.addEventListener("click", cBoton);

/* HTML */

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button onclick="addDiv()">add</button>
<button onclick="cBoton()">Click Me</button>
<frameset><legend>recursions</legend>
<div id="div1"></div>
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answered without it...